# Starting aspell in email mode

Tags: emacs, aspell

In spite of going through [the aspell documentation](http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/4_Customizing.html#SECTION00541300000000000000), I cannot get it to skip over quoted text, as the email mode is expected to do. I have the following in my .emacs.d file:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook (lambda ()                                            
  (setq ispell-extra-args '("--mode=email"))))
```

Aspell, however, keeps spell checking the quoted message, even although `C-h v ispell-extra-args` returns `Its value is ("--mode=email")`. I should also point out that executing aspell from the command line does not ignore the `--mode=email` option, so there seems not to be anything wrong with aspell itself.

Comment: Do you use flyspell or do you use something like ispell-region/buffer/word?

Comment: @Stefan: `ispell-buffer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you need to look onto `ispell-message` function from the same package. It will spell check body of your message & Subject header, but will exclude other headers & cited mail. In function's description (`C-h f ispell-message`) you can find examples of hooks for `mail-send` & `message-send` commands...

Comment: I have found that ispell-message is ignoring the text inserted before the first quote — in other words; text before the first ">" is not being spell-checked. Do you know if this is the intended behavior?

Comment: No, I don't know about this problem - I just checked on my Emacs (24.1) and it checked text before & after citation

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1. That might explain the difference.